# android xml error: 'class' or 'interface' required

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-studio

I am new to android development. Here is my XML code for one of an activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.*****.*****.DisplayMessageActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As seen above, I want the TextView to have id view_text. But as soon as I write android:id="@+id/view_text", it gives an **error saying 'class' or 'interface' expected.**

There are no errors in any of the other files. As soon as I remove android:id="@+id/view_text", everything works perfectly fine.

Also I am using the latest version of android studio. Just this problem.

DisplayMessageActivity:
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_text);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try to clean and build your project and check.

Comment: I did the same file as yours no such error

Comment: Iv tried to clean and rebuild it several times.

Comment: `com.example.*****.*****.DisplayMessageActivity`. Is this really a class??

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this should not work! Is it something to do with android studio not working properly?

Comment: com.example.*****.*****.DisplayMessageActivity. I have just put **** instead of actual names in there to protect the privacy of the project. And DisplayMessageActivity is an actual class

Comment: Out of curiosity, is DisplayMessageActivity registered in your manifest?

Comment: post some activity code and logcat...

Comment: DisplayMessageActivity is indeed registered in my manifest.

Comment: this is DisplayMessageActivity:

Comment: oops - i thought you were having trouble with the activity.

Comment: what happens if you change the id to something else?

Comment: the error is still there. It seems that this error occurs only when I use TextView. Any other view like EditText etc.. works. Very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the effect of accidentally invoking Inject Language, place the caret inside the literal string where you injected the language (e.g.  somewhere in `@dimen/view_text` in your first screenshot) and then invoke "show intention actions" (<kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>Option-Enter</kbd> on Mac). One of the last options in the menu should be "Un-inject Language ".

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me